# Disable RootStateOrAny in React typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Every time I want to use `useSelector` I have to do something like this:

```
const isLoading = useSelector(
    (state: RootStateOrAny) => state.utils.isLoading
  );
```

Is there a way to disable needing to type out `RootStateOrAny` every time? It's getting annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  First, you should *not* be using the `RootStateOrAny` type - that's an internal type from React-Redux.  Instead you should be using your own app's `RootState` type.

Second, you should specifically follow our recommended Redux + TypeScript setup guidelines, and [create a "pre-typed" version of the `useSelector` hook](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start#define-typed-hooks), like:

```
// hooks.ts
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store'

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

and then use those pre-typed hooks everywhere.